# ASP.NET MVC Forum software using ASP.NET Membership?

Tags: asp.net, forum

Does anybody know of any free ASP.NET forum software than can integrate with an ASP.NET MVC site that runs on the ASP.NET membership API?

Answer (score 1):

YetAnotherForum (YAF) is a popular open source .NET based discussion forum. It's been a while since I last worked with it but the latest 1.9.3 release is meant to integrate with the ASP.NET membership providers:

http://www.yetanotherforum.net/

Comment: Thanks.

Do you know if its able to integrate well with an ASP.NET MVC site? (Guess I should have put that in my main post)